# gulp browsersync reload not detecting changes

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I am still working on my gulpfile.js script as I moved from a mac to windows laptop.

Why is the reload not working? I've been crawling through the internet finding examples for gulp.watch .on('change'...) but not finding the right solution to it.

The script works fine with converting pug, scss and js files and putting all together as well as opening a new browser tab.

My browsersync section looks as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
const minify = require('gulp-minify');
var colors = require('colors');
const fs = require('fs');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var path = require('path');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

var projectFolder = process.env.INIT_CWD;
var directFolder = projectFolder.split("htdocs")[1];
var name = process.argv[4];
var template = process.argv[6];
var systemplatform = process.platform;

// Compile Sass Files
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    if(fs.existsSync(projectFolder) && projectFolder.includes('_projects')){
        var sassFiles = projectFolder+'/scss/*.scss';
        var cssDest = projectFolder+'/_dist/css/';
        return gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    }
    else{
        return console.log(colors.redBG('Maybe switch into your current project folder?'));
    }
});

// Compile Pug Files
gulp.task('pug-php', function() {
    if(fs.existsSync(projectFolder) && projectFolder.includes('_projects')){
        return gulp.src(projectFolder+'/pug/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.php'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(projectFolder+'/_dist/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    }else{
        return console.log(colors.redBG('Maybe switch into your current project folder?'));
    }
});

// Compile Pug Files
gulp.task('pug', function() {
    if(fs.existsSync(projectFolder) && projectFolder.includes('_projects')){
        return gulp.src(projectFolder+'/pug/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.html'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(projectFolder+'/_dist/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    }else{
        return console.log(colors.redBG('Maybe switch into your current project folder?'));
    }
});

// Copy assets
gulp.task('copy', function() {
    if(fs.existsSync(projectFolder) && projectFolder.includes('_projects')){
        return gulp.src(projectFolder+'/assets/**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(projectFolder+'/_dist/assets/'));
    }else{
        return console.log(colors.redBG('Maybe switch into your current project folder?'));
    }
});

// Compile JS Files
gulp.task('js', function() {
    if(fs.existsSync(projectFolder) && projectFolder.includes('_projects')){
        return gulp.src(projectFolder+'/js/*.js')
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(projectFolder+'/_dist/js/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    }else{
        return console.log(colors.redBG('Maybe switch into your current project folder?'));
    }
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    var routePage = directFolder+'/_dist/';
    browserSync.init({
        injectChanges: true,
        startPath: routePage,
        proxy: 'localhost',
        browser: "chrome"
    })
    if(name == undefined){
        var file = 'index.html';
    }else{
        var elements = name.split('/').length;
        var file = name.split('/')[elements-1];
        file = file.replace('pug', 'html');
    }
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/pug/**/*.pug', gulp.task('pug')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/scss/*.scss', gulp.task('sass')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/js/*.js', gulp.task('js')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/assets/**/*.*', gulp.task('copy')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/_dist/'+file).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    console.log(colors.green('Watching '+routePage+''+file));
});

gulp.task('browserSync-php', function() {
    var routePage = directFolder+'/_dist/';
    browserSync.init({
        injectChanges: true,
        startPath: routePage,
        proxy: 'localhost',
        browser: "chrome"
    })
    if(name == undefined){
        var file = 'index.php';
    }else{
        var elements = name.split('/').length;
        var file = name.split('/')[elements-1];
        file = file.replace('pug', 'php');
    }
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/pug/**/*.pug', gulp.task('pug-php')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/scss/*.scss', gulp.task('sass')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/js/*.js', gulp.task('js')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/assets/**/*.*', gulp.task('copy')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(process.env.INIT_CWD+'/_dist/'+file).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    console.log(colors.green('Watching '+routePage+''+file));
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('sass', 'pug', 'js', 'copy', 'browserSync'));
gulp.task('watch-php', gulp.series('sass', 'pug-php', 'js', 'copy', 'browserSync-php'));

gulp.task('new', function() {
    if(fs.existsSync(projectFolder+'/'+name+'/')){
        return console.log(colors.redBG('The project "'+name+'" already exists in this folder!'));
    }else{
        if(projectFolder.includes('_projects')) {
            if(name == undefined){
                return console.log(colors.redBG('You need to define a --name XYZ for your project'));
            }else{
                console.log(colors.green('Creating new project named "'+name+'" in _projects'));
                path = projectFolder+'/'+name+'/';
                if(template == undefined){
                    var tempPath = './templates/_default';
                }else{
                    var tempPath = './templates/'+template;
                }
                return gulp.src(tempPath+'/**/')
                .pipe(gulp.dest(path)),
                gulp.src(tempPath+'/**/*.*')
                .pipe(gulp.dest(path));
            }        
        }else{
            return console.log(colors.redBG('You need to be in your "_projects" folder to create a new project'));
        }
    }
});
```

It seems that the script is not seeing / watching the files (pug, scss,...) and that's why when I change and save them, nothing happens.

Anybody a quickfix for this problem or any other information needed?

Thank you in advance,
Lars

Comment: need to see all of your gulp file

Comment: @MohamedTalaat I edited my question and posted full script, thanks!

Comment: please try this => 
- remove .create from require statement;
- write a function for browser-sync only 
function browser_sync() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: "your dir-name",
    },
    options: {
      reloadDelay: 250,
    },
    notify: false,
  });
}
- replace stream with 
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
- try run browser-sync init function at the end of your watch function not at the start.
please try all the above and let me know. :)

https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate

Comment: can you please share you demo project on github so I can try on ?

Comment: @MohamedTalaat https://github.com/Koalabaer79/landingpages/tree/testing - please use this repository for your testings

Comment: please have a look on this repo until I invistigate the issue.
https://github.com/Mohamed-Talaat333/gulp-boilerplate